# Making class codable

Tags: swift, codable, decodable

I have a protocol, that is Codable and a class, that is Codable :

```
public protocol SourceListItem: AnyObject, Codable
{
    var name: String { get set }
    var children: [SourceListItem] { get set }
}

final public class SourceListHeader: Codable
{
    var name: String = "Give me a name!"
    var children: [SourceListItem] = [SourceListItem]()
}
```

However, the complier give me two errors :

```
Type 'SourceListHeader' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'
Type 'SourceListHeader' does not conform to protocol 'Codable'
```

Why is that? I can't fix the error, and I have tried many variations...

The issue seems to come from the protocol, because if I remove it, everything works fine. It is like the compiler fails to see that the protocol only applies to Codable classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a concrete type conforming to `Codable`, you can't use a protocol conforming to `Codable`.

```
final public class SourceListHeader<Item: Codable>: Codable {
    var name: String = "Give me a name!"
    var children = [Item]()
}
```

Comment: That's so good... thx. What's the difference between declaring `class SourceListHeader<Item: SourceListItem>:Codable` and using `var children: [Item] = [Item]()` and declaring `class SourceListHeader:Codable` and using `var children: [SourceListItem] = [SourceListItem]()`. To me it looks like `<Item: SourceListItem>` only tells the compiler that Item conforms to `SourceListItem`... which is the same as `var children: [SourceListItem]`

Comment: `Item` is a concrete type conforming to `Codable`, while `SourceListItem` is a protocol inheriting from `Codable`. However, [Protocols don't conform to themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself), hence the need for generics.